# Error C1071: Unexpected end of file found in comment due to /* in #ifdeffed out raw string literal

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Why does this code give a "Error C1071: Unexpected end of file found in comment" error?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#if 0
   std::string script = R"(#!/bin/sh
ls /mnt/*.txt
)";
#endif
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 16.7.5.

Comment: This problem still exists in Visual Studio 17.1.0 Preview 1.1

Comment: Link to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qanbo6Ecc) example, the same problem I have described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/BUG-Raw-string-literal-with--inside-/10080232).

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a compiler bug.  I have submitted a ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-C1071:-Unexpected-end-of-file-foun/1592300?entry=myfeedback

Here is some more data.  **A workaround would be to not use a raw string literal with this character sequence.**

```
#include <iostream>

// VS 16.7.5

int main()
{
#if 1
   std::string script = R"(#!/bin/sh
ls /ok/*.txt
)";
#endif

#if 0
   std::string script = R"(#!/bin/sh
ls /not_ok/*.txt
)";
#endif

#if 0
   std::string script = R"(#!/bin/sh
//ls /compiles_but_invalid_script/*.txt
)";
#endif

#if 0
   std::string script = "(#!/bin/sh\nls /and_this_is_ok/*.txt";
#endif
}
```